# showing invalid foreign key django

Tags: django

[I am getting this invalid foreign key error in calendars, not sure how to fix it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8BBL.png)

Here is the code in my models:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to link it to the logged in user, but I don't think it is working. I also tried to print the entries in django shell, but it also gives an error of "NameError: name 'Calendar' is not defined" with this query:

```
calendars = calendars.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

### What is wrong?

It seems like you have an invalid `Calendar` record in your database.

Based on the definition of the `owner` field, it should store the ID of a `User` record that is the owner of this `Calendar`.

However, looking at your error message:

> The row in table 'calendars_calendar' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: calendar_calendar.owner_id contains a value 'owner id' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user.id.

This suggests that your `calendars_calendar` table has a record like this:

```
| id | owner_id |
|----|----------|
| 1  | owner id |
```

This is not valid since the value of the `owner_id` column should be the primary key of a record in the `auth_user` table.

### Why did this happen?/How to fix it?

This invalid record might have entered your database because you used a raw SQL query or a change in model definition. Nonetheless, you have to fix this for this record to work.

If you know the ID of the `User` that should be the owner of this `Calender`, you can set it using this query:

```py
Calender.objects.filter(id=1).update(owner_id=<USER_ID_OF_OWNER>)
```

### Why didn't your query work?

`NameError: name 'Calendar' is not defined` suggests that you are referencing the `Calender` class where it is not defined.
Perhaps you forgot to import it?

### Tips

Usually, including the error text for errors like this (that are textual) in your question is easier to use than linking an image.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I couldn't manage to get it fixed, so I deleted the databases and migrations and start over and it seems to work fine